# How I can show the navigational bar icon on the left of my customized action bar

Tags: android-layout, android-actionbar, android

I have customized my action bar with the following:

- Title at the center
- Title with customized font from asset
- Title does not have the application icon

[image]

What I want is the navigational drawer icon on left. 
Right now you can see it is on the left of the title My App. I want to have my application title on center only without the navigational drawer icon.
I tried with ImageView inside my customized action bar layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/iv_nav_drawr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_navbar_drawer" />

<TextView

android:id="@+id/apptitle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:text="@string/app_name" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

my activity code snippet for the action bar customization is:

```
    private void actionBarCustomizations(){

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    //getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.app_action_bar, null);
    TextView actionBarTitleTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.apptitle);
Typeface neoTechMedium = 
Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),   "fonts/NeoTech-Bold.ttf");
    actionBarTitleTextView.setTypeface(neoTechMedium);

    ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new 
 ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER); 

    getActionBar().setCustomView(v, params);

}
```

Any one can help me on this please?

Answer (score 0):

HI Remove layout_gravity, and gravity from Image View.
Just Use

```
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

It's in ImageView property Ok...

Comment: and If you want to make it center in vertical then Use this property  android:layout_centerVertical="true"

Comment: Thanks for spending time on my problem I really really appreciate that. tried.

Comment: try this one Remove layout_gravity="center" from Relative Layout and use above said property to Image View...